# How can I view the list of channels I have sent at least one message to on Slack?

Tags: slack

How can I view the list of channels I have sent at least one message to on Slack?

Comment: I don't think that is possible through the standard UI, but you can certainly build an app that gives you that info. Would suggest asking this question on stackoverflow.